# How to get Django ModelForm to accept a date in a particular format (or convert to an acceptable fomat)?

Tags: django, forms, date, model, format

I have a model with a datefield. I am using this model to create a form using the ModelForm class.

The problem is that the user can enter the date in multiple formats (d-m-yy, dd-mm-yy, dd-mm-yyyy) (not thinking about locales for now). 
After the form is submitted. Django form.is_valid() fails because of the date format.

I need to handle different formats but can't figure out how to do that. Here is a minimal Form and Model class: (assume correct imports)

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.MyDateModel
        fields = ["date"]

        widgets = {

            "date":   forms.DateInput(),
        }
```

Model Class

```
class MyDateModel(models.Model): 
    date = models.DateField()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13459588/10586134).

Or you can add `clean_date` function to your form class, check date input using regex and convert it to Django datetime format. Something like this:

```
import datetime, re


class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...

    def clean_date(date):
        date = self.cleaned_data.get('date')
        if re.match('^\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{2}', date) is not None:
            return datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%d-%m-%y").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        if re.match('^\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}', date) is not None:
            return datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%d-%m-%Y").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

Comment: Ended up using a DateField like in the link you provided. With some javascript to ensure only selected formats are submitted.